# Saving data with table associations in Grails

Tags: database, model-view-controller, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have two database tables 'Student' and 'Course'. I want a one-to-one relation where there is foreign key of 'Course' table in 'Student' table. The foreign key 'course_id' is appearing in the Student table but whenever I try to save the Student data (after filling form), the data does not get saved and there is no error as well. I am very new to grails. Please guide me how I can save the data correctly.

The table structure is as desired but the data is not getting saved to the database. There is no issue with other code parts because the data is getting saved when I remove the association between the two tables.

> Student controller

```
package com.grails

class studentController {
    def save(Student student){
        student.save()
    }
}
```

> Student domain class

```
class Student {
    Course course

    String firstName
    String lastName
}
```

> Course domain class

```
class Course{
    String course_name
    String duration

    static hasOne = [student: Student]

    //static belongsTo = [student: Student]
}
```

Comment: You can call `save` with flag `failOnError`, e.g. `student.save(failOnError: true)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I applied this with a try catch block and found out that there was a validation error which was preventing the save(). I modified my association and now it is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that grails 4 introduced a bug with one-to-one relationships that gives inconsistent behavior based on the owning side of the relationship: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11606

I'm not sure if this is the same problem you may be seeing without more information on your error, or even if you're on this version of grails.

Comment: I am using grails 3. I have solved my issue which was caused by a validation error which occurred in the controller. But thanks for notifying about the bug in grails 4, it will be helpful for me while using version 4